# Artifactory 7.2.1 - How to change the listening address for Artifactory and UI

Tags: artifactory

I've installed the latest Artifactory-Pro package via rpm (7.2.1). I've notice that in the latest version the UI is accessed through port 8082 and Artifactory still listens on port 8081. Both these services are listening on address 0.0.0.0.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8082            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8081            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

How can I change the listening address of these services?

I've tried setting the node.ip on settings.xml but it still doesn't work.

```
shared:
  node:
    ip: 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the Artifactory address by using the Tomcat connector extraConfig parameter in the [system.yaml](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+System+YAML#ArtifactorySystemYAML-SharedConfigurations) (this parameter allows configuring the Tomcat [connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html)):

```
artifactory:

    tomcat:

        connector:

            extraConfig: address="127.0.0.1"
```

Configuring the binding address for the [router](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/System+Architecture) service (port 8082) is not possible at the moment. It will be available in one of the upcoming releases.

Comment: This does not work anymore in 7.4 since jfrog changed the template, setting the address to localhost there. Remote access is not possible anymore. Any updates to this? Changing the template helps for now.